# component store is corrupted - 0x800f081f

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, updates, dism

I had problem install windows update.

I found in event log problem with component store.

First I check component store with **Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool.**

**Scanhealth**

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
```

**Result**

```
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

**CheckHealth**

```
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
```

**Result**

```
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

So I tried **repair** component store.

```
DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

**Result with errror**

```
The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not found or the comp
onent store cannot be repaired.

Error: 0x800f081f

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.
```

I checked log `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\DISM.log` but there is no error.

```
Checking System Update Readiness.


    Summary:
    Operation: Detect and Repair 
    Operation result: 0x0
    Last Successful Step: Entire operation completes.
    Total Detected Corruption:  0
        CBS Manifest Corruption:    0
        CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
        CSI Manifest Corruption:    0
        CSI Metadata Corruption:    0
        CSI Payload Corruption: 0
    Total Repaired Corruption:  0
        CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
        CSI Manifest Repaired:  0
        CSI Payload Repaired:   0
        CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   True

    Total Operation Time: 545 seconds.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

[Here is complete DISM log](http://pastebin.com/b7zL3M7g).

**EDITED**

I also ran `sfc / scannow`

**Result**

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations
```

[Here is CBS.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11udsmopq1i6qpv/CBS.log)

Comment: Run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt, then post a link to the resulting `CBS.log` file.

Comment: @and31415: I ran sfc but no problem found. I uploded CBC log.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, that I already reported a while ago to Microsoft.

Your issue is fixed by DISM, but due to the bug is still reports an error. Ignore the error.

Comment: Is there an MSDN reference or similar for this bug?

Comment: no, there is no reference. I can't share my email conversations ;)

Comment: I would like ignore this "bug" but this "bug" is reason why I can not install KB2919355 :(.

Comment: @Jan where do you want to know that this is the cause? Please share the CBS logs of the setup failure.

Comment: @magicandre1981. u can dowload CBS log here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/11udsmopq1i6qpv/CBS.log

Comment: the last error is 2 days ago. Do you still get it now? Also try to install the Update and give me the logs which includes the errors of the setup failure of the Update KB2919355.

Comment: @ magicandre1981: yes, problem is still same :(

Comment: I need the latest logs

Comment: @magicandre1984: here is CBC log https://www.dropbox.com/s/9en64dc3vr92wxp/CBS.rar

Comment: the **ieetwproxystub.dll** in **amd64_microsoft-windows-ie-ieetwcollector_31bf3856ad364e35_11.0.9600.16384_none_c6dbf8e4e5bb5bc5** is corrupt and this leads into the **ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT** error. Try to fix it with the good old inlace upgrade: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thank you for your explanation. If I have a time a make fresh win installation. You could post this result to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Are you from Microsoft?

Comment: @Pacerier no, I don't work for Microsoft.

Comment: @magicandre1981, You seem to know many of the internals of Windows. How do you go about Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier I learned how this works by trial&error when we coded/tested the first tool to integrate the Vista Sp1 (before vLite was ale to do it)

Comment: @magicandre1981, Which books do you recommend do be good at Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier  there are no books about the servicing stack

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by doing an upgrade with the Win 8.1+Update DVD (I used en_windows_8.1_with_update_x64_dvd_4065090.iso from MSDN).

This kept all data, settings and apps.